# I deleted every mail on my iPhone - but why does Mail still eat up my memory?

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

I deleted every single mail from Mail.app on iOS 8.3 (inbox, sent, trash). However, Mail still occupies 798 MB for "mails and attachments" according to the memory overview. How can I clear this memory?

Comment: Reboot the phone.

Comment: @Tetsujin I did ...

Comment: Sync; backup; restore would be 2nd suggestion

Answer (score 2):

According to OS X Daily, you can try removing the account from the mail app and adding it again. [Source](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/11/recover-mail-attachment-storage-space-ios/)

Comment: Yes this worked, but it's an awful thing to have to do each time. For the record, I did this 3 months ago, and had to do it again today to clear 2.4GB of space. On a 16GB phone, that space is quickly missed. I assumed that a daily sync to clean out pix would be enough, but the mail app goes in this ridiculous cycle....

Answer (score 1):

Tetsujin is correct, backup the phone, then go into settings -> general -> reset and erase all settings and data. Then restore the phone from the backup you just created. The available space should be better.

One thing I learned a couple of years ago and not sure if it still applies. If you do a hard reset (Sleep and home buttons pressed until the phone reboots) three times in a row, IOS will do some rather intensive cleanup and file system checks after the 3rd reboot. That might help. Not sure but it is quicker than backup/restore and won't hurt a thing.

Comment: hard power off is harsh on the phone, just make sure the phone fully boots and is not loading any apps or writing any data when you do a hard reset (sleep plus home button - hold down together 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Go to iTunes and try to buy or rent a movie with more memory needs than your device has available OR just go to TV app and try to download a movie you already own that is larger than the space you have available.  You will be informed you do not have enough memory, and this will clear memory caches, especially email ones, freeing up more memory.  This method increased my memory available from 780MB to 2GB

Comment: What a devious way to spend money. I wonder if trying to play a movie you already purchased will work.

Comment: I think it checks your storage before asking you to pay, so you shouldn’t have to actually buy/rent it.